# How to tell which QGIS plugins are slow to load?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

We have new users of QGIS in our office that are dismayed immediately by the startup time of QGIS - which hangs on the 'Restoring Loaded Plugins' message on the splash screen.

Is there a way to tell which plugins take long to load and are causing QGIS to load slowly? This can sometimes take ~1minute!

The only solution so far is to disable almost every plugin that comes with the default installation and bring back the plugins one by one as you need them - but so far we haven't figured out which default plugin is causing the slow load time.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Hidden feature that I never made a UI for

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(qgis.utils.plugin_times)
```

Run it in the Python console

Also see the **plugin** called **Plugin Load Times**: (https://gitlab.com/GIS-projects/Plugin-Load-Times)

Comment: +1, would love to see a button for this somewhere in the UI of `Manage and Install Plugins... > Settings` :)

Comment: @Nathan W: I wanted to sort the results, so i gave it a try: https://gist.github.com/neogis-de/3dfa66180c3506cb0d87f40895ba36c0

Comment: In 2.16 there is also a runtime profiler class which which times other parts of the code, mainly the load times.  I will look at making a report interface for them all.

Comment: A timely answer to a question that has been bugging me too. Perhaps a gui for it is now timely?

Comment: I wonder if there is also a way to measure how long each layer takes to load?

Comment: I made a standalone tool for that but could be ported as a plugin to break down load times easy enough

Comment: @Nathan W :Is your standalone tool somewhere on github to give it a try?

Comment: https://github.com/DMS-Aus/qgis2img

Comment: @Nathan W I tried qgis2img but the benchmark seems to be a bit 'optimistic'. Loading time in QGIS is about 1:05min and in qgis2img for project and layers together 24,6 seconds. Any idea why there is such a difference?

Comment: @Nathan and perhaps add a plugin loading time total?

Comment: I run QGIS 3.6 on 2 laptops and one desktop. The desktop takes a very long time to load.   I do notice that after restart it is better.